# axis tick labels at irregular intervals - wpf toolkit chart

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, linechart

[image]

I am using wpf toolkit chart control. Using Area series to draw the chart. 
I want to show only custom interval labels at x-axis. They don't fit in any series or interval. Please see the image. As shown in the image I only want to show 1,9,13,20,26,35 ticks on the x-axis.

Any idea would be appreciated about how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally by hit and trial I was able to find the solution. I overrided GetLabelValues method of LinearAxis class and passed it a list of valid tick marks. See the code below.

```
public class EquiDistanceAxis : LinearAxis
{
    List<int> validValues;


    public List<int> ValidValues
    {
        get { return validValues; }
    }


    public EquiDistanceAxis()
        : base()
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Implemented.");
    }

    public EquiDistanceAxis(List<int> input)
        : base()
    {
        validValues = input;
    }


    protected override IEnumerable<IComparable> GetLabelValues(Size availableSize)
    {
        IEnumerable<IComparable> tickMarkEnumerator = base.GetLabelValues(availableSize);
        var enumerator = tickMarkEnumerator.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            int day = Convert.ToInt32(enumerator.Current);
            if (validValues.Any(v => v == day))
                yield return day;
        }

    }


}
```